# Unable to import main file inside test

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am unable to import the main file inside my tests. Here is what my directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── invoker.py
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
├── script.py
├── template_generators
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── flipper.py
│   └── psp22.py
├── templates
│   ├── flipper
│   │   ├── cargo.txt
│   │   └── flipper.txt
│   └── psp22
│       ├── cargo.txt
│       └── psp22.txt
└── tests
    ├── template_generators
    │   ├── test_flipper.py
    │   └── test_psp22.py
    └── test_cli.py
```

I want to import main inside test_cli.py

Here is how main.py looks like

```
import typer

from invoker import Invoker

def main() -> None:
    
    print("Welcome to Ink Wizard!")
    print("Type 1 to scaffold flipper contract")
    print("Type 2 to scaffold psp22 contract")

    contract_type = typer.prompt("Enter your choice to continue")

    if contract_type == "1":
        Invoker.flipper()
        print("flipper scaffolded")
    if contract_type == "2":
        contract_name = typer.prompt("Please enter name of contract")
        Invoker.psp22(contract_name=contract_name, mintable=mintable, metadata=metadata, burnable=burnable, wrapper=wrapper, flashmint=flashmint, pausable=pausable, capped=capped)
        print("psp22 contract scaffolded")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

Here is my `test_cli.py`

```
import typer
from typer.testing import CliRunner

import main

app = typer.Typer()
app.command()(main)

runner = CliRunner()

def test_cli() -> None:
    result = runner.invoke(app, [])
    assert result.exit_code == 0
```

When I run python `test_cli.py`, here is the error I am getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

If anyone can give me an example on how to import main inside test_cli. That would be great. Thanks

Comment: Does your PYTHONPATH points to the root of the main folder?
Are you able to open a python console and run `import main`?

Comment: @MenyIssakov I am able to import main inside root directory. In the tests/ directory, I am unable to do so.

Comment: How are you running your tests?

Comment: @dmontaner Tests that are inside the package are running fine. Problem is, main does not belong to any package so I am unable to import it. One way to test it to move `test_cli.py` in the root directory.

Answer (score -1):

quite dumb answer, but whatever. If you want just test your main. you can manually paste your main inside same folder where your test is located and then it should work.

Comment: I moved my test file to the root. It works now.